# Zoom div content on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I want to make div content resizable, but the div itself to stay the same size. This should happen when the user scrolls. I have this function:

```
var zoomable = document.getElementById('zoomable'),
    zX = 1;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var dir;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    dir = (e.deltaY > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    zX += dir;
    zoomable.style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')';
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```

This works but only with the div itself. In this div I have multiple small draggable tables with `.foo` class and I want to resize them without changing parents size. I have also tried this:

```
var zoomable = document.getElementsByClassName('foo'),
    zX = 1;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var dir;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    dir = (e.deltaY > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    zX += dir;
    zoomable.each(function(){ 
        $(this).style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')'; 
    })
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```

But is does not work either. Is there a way to resize content but not the div?

EDIT: Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/ba2n9a61/
It's not exactly my project (Because it's too complex), but the idea is the same. I want to make `#zoomable` div to stay the same size and its content (paragraphs in this case) to be resizable.

Comment: Please create a working fiddle.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital I've added jsfiddle. If you could help me with this, I would be really glad.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze I've made fiddle for you in my answer is that what you want ?

Comment: What browser are you using to test this? In everyone's fiddles I see no resizing or animation whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adjusted your fiddle to work. I think this is what you wanted. You need to target your content to make this work like your description.

```
var content = document.getElementById('zoomable').getElementsByTagName('p');
var zX = 1;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var dir;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    dir = (e.deltaY > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    zX += dir;
    for (var i = 0; i<content.length; i++) {
         content[i].style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')';
        }

    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Karadjordje1389/z254o87v/

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Happy to help :)

Comment: I have one more question, maybe you could help. This code works fine in FF, Chrome and IE, but not in safari. What could be the problem?

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze As for JS it this should work in safari. I have actually tested it on safari with MAC and it works, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have modified this code a little, because now I need zoom to work on scroll, without ctrl key. Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512450/cant-detect-mouse-wheel-event-in-safari I have created jsfiddle as well, you can test it.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze As far as I can see somebody already answered your question :)

Comment: Yes, there is one answer, but still same, does not work in safari. See the fiddle and test it in different browsers.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Okay so you want zoom to work on your right div with id #mainDiv ?

Comment: On the tables in the #mainDiv. #mainDiv itself should remain the same size.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Okay I saw your problem it can be solved with JQ pretty easy but unfortunately I have to leave now, so I can help you with this later during this day with this not now.

Comment: Glad to hear that. No problem, I'll wait :)

Comment: @Also update your question with more details what you are trying to do. I mean in that new question thread.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze I have tested your code in safari and it works.

Comment: Well, that's weird... Ok, I'll try it on another machine when I can.