# Can't detect mouse wheel event in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm trying to detect mouse wheel event to resize elements on scroll. I have `#mainDiv` with several `.foo` tables inside. I want to change `.foo` element's scale on scroll, but leave `#mainDiv`'s size the same. This is my function:

```
        var content = document.getElementById('mainDiv').getElementsByClassName('foo');
        var zX = 1;

        $('#mainDiv').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dir;
            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0){
                dir = 0.05;
            }
            else{
                dir = -0.05;
            }
            zX += dir;
            for (var i = 0; i<content.length; i++) {
                content[i].style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')';
            }
            return;
        });
```

This function works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but not in safari. What's the problem?

EDIT: `.foo` elements don't have display property. Can that be a problem? I just don't want to set it because of the functionality of my app.

EDIT 2: I have created jsfiddle to play with code. It's pretty big but we need only first function in javascript block.

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/cg3hkde7/9/

Drag few items to the right side and press "Add new link". Then scroll. Tables will change their size, but not in Safari. Also, if you are familiar with jsPlumb, maybe you could help, why endpoints don't change their location and size.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code might help you

```js
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("wheel", myfns);

function myfns(){

  console.log("wheel");

}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">scroll on me!</div>
```

Following is jquery code

```js
var count = 0;
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
  console.log("wheel " + count++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target" style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px; height: 100px;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Reference

https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

I have edited your code now mouse scroll work for me try it hope it will works

```js
var setZoom = function(z, el, instance) {
  instance = instance || jsPlumb;
  var p = ["-webkit-", "-moz-", "-ms-", "-o-", ""],
    s = "scale(" + z + ")";
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    //el.css(p[i] + "transform", s);          //FIRST WAY TO TRANSFORM
    el.style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')'; //SECOND WAY TO TRANSFORM
  }
  instance.setZoom(z);
};

var content = document.getElementById('mainDiv').getElementsByClassName('foo');
var zX = 1;
$('#mainDiv').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var dir;
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    dir = 0.05;
  } else {
    dir = -0.05;
  }
  if ((zX + dir) >= 0.05) {
    zX += dir;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')';
    setZoom(zX, content[i]);
  }
  return;
});






var count = 0;
$("#leftDiv").scroll(function() {
  console.log("wheel " + count++);
});














































$('#deviceName li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#interface li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#display li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#output li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$('#streams li').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid'
});

function foo() {
  $('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      containment: $(this).parent(),
      stack: '.foo'
    });
  });
}
var fooCount = $('.foo').length;
$('#mainDiv').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('foo')) {
      var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
      var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
      var item = $('<table class="foo elementTable ' + Class + '" name="' + title + '" id="' + (fooCount + 1) + '"><tr class="tableHeader"><th class="thClass"><button class="settings">set</button>' + title + '<span class="close">x</span></th></tr><tr><td class="add"><span class="addList">Add new link</span></td></tr></table>');
      $(this).append(item);
      fooCount += 1;
      foo();
    }
  }
});

var ListCount = $('.tableConn').length;
$("body").on('click', '.addList', function() {
  var newtr = '<tr class="tableBody" id="' + ListCount + '_' + ListCount + '"><td class="tableConn">Link ' + (ListCount + 1) + '</td></tr>';
  ListCount += 1;
  $(newtr).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent());
  addPoints();

});

function addPoints() {
  jsPlumb.setContainer("mainDiv");
  jsPlumb.draggable($('.foo'));
  $('.tableBody').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('jsplumb-endpoint-anchor')) {
      var objId = $(this).attr("id");
      jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), {
        anchor: "Right",
        isSource: true,
        isTarget: false,
        connector: "Bezier",
        endpoint: ["Image", {
          url: "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png",
          width: 17,
          height: 17
        }],
        connectorStyle: {
          strokeStyle: "grey",
          lineWidth: 3
        },
        connectorHoverStyle: {
          lineWidth: 3
        },
        maxConnections: -1,
        uuid: $(this).attr("id") + 'r'
      });
      jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), {
        anchor: "Left",
        isSource: false,
        isTarget: true,
        connector: "Bezier",
        endpoint: ["Image", {
          url: "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png",
          width: 17,
          height: 17
        }],
        connectorStyle: {
          strokeStyle: "grey",
          lineWidth: 3
        },
        connectorHoverStyle: {
          lineWidth: 3
        },
        uuid: $(this).attr("id") + 'l'
      });
    }
  });
}

jsPlumb.bind("connectionDetached", function(connection) {
  connection.targetEndpoint.setImage("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png");
  connection.sourceEndpoint.setImage("https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/868142-200.png");
});
```

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#leftDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

#deviceInfo {
  min-height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  padding: 3px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

#settingsDiv {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 82%;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}

.foo {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
}

.thClass {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableConn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.close {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

#settingsDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.settings {
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.settingsform {
  padding: 5px;
}

.streamsettings {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.leftset {
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 20px;
}

.rightset {
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.streamsettings .rightset input {
  width: 100%;
}

.addList {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addList:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head runat="server">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.1.8/jsPlumb.js"></script>
    <style>
      .jsplumb-endpoint {
        z-index: 10;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="leftDiv" style="overflow: scroll;">
      <div id="deviceInfo">
        <button id="black">dark</button>
        <button id="white">light</button>
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>Device Name
            <ul id="deviceName">
              <li>
                itenisalm 1
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Interface
            <ul id="interface">
              <li>
                item 2
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Display
            <ul id="display">
              <li>
                item 3
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Output
            <ul id="output">
              <li>
                item 4
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button id="btn">create</button>
        <input type="button" id="save" name="save" value="save" />
        <input type="button" id="load" name="load" value="load" />
      </div>
      <div id="settingsDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I need to detect when the users scroll with the wheel, not when they click it.

Comment: Okay I will edit the answer following is MDN document link for browser compatibility with mouse will event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

Comment: I have tried your version, still the same. Every browser detects scroll event except Safari...

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze If your are okay with jquery we can give try this using jquery.

Comment: I'm okay with it. We can try. Is there another way to do this with jquery?

Comment: Does not work... I have created working jsfiddle where you can see the problem and try codes if you want.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze I edited your code try it now works for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159990/discussion-between-vaxo-basilidze-and-nisal-edu).